# Implementing a 2-Dimensional Position for Java

Tags: java, position

I want to know what I should use for 2-dimensional positions for a Sprite.

- I see `Dimension` objects referring to *size*, mainly around GUI components.
- I was thinking about doing `int[2]`, but it could easily be sabotaged by inserting in an empty array or one with the incorrect number of elements.
- I only see `Point` objects around Mouse positions, so I don't know if it has the same purpose as what I'm looking for.

I have no idea what to choose for my purpose.

Comment: Why not make your own?

Comment: @kcraigie I don't want to create my own if there's already a class that fulfills the purpose; it'd be redundant.

Comment: You effectively want a Point, so that sounds as good as any other structure.